# Looking for a piano sight reading app that listens to your instrument

Tags: android, music, ios

I've been looking around for a sight reading app.  I found [this rather excellent iPad app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sight-reading-hd/id373465060?mt=8) and it has helped a lot.  I'd really like an app that allows me to practice using my instrument instead of an on screen keyboard (that will preferably tell me when I've gone wrong).

I've done a lot of searching, but I haven't found any apps that actually listen to your instrument.

I found [this related question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/444/what-is-good-software-for-learning-how-to-sight-read), but the answers were mainly for desktop software.  I need something that will run on one of my tablets (IOS or Android).

<sub>Note, this question was originally asked on 
[Musical Practice & Performance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22948/looking-for-a-piano-sight-reading-app-that-listens-to-your-instrument) and someone suggested that I ask on Software Recommendations instead.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Check out 'Pitch' on the apple app store:
https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id989140910?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=6

It shows random notes and listens for the note you play. You get a point for each right note.
Here is the website:
http://www.practicemakesperfect.education

You can change clef and key signatures with an in app purchase.

Hope this helps.